# Openshift docker cli in jenkins pipeline

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, openshift

I'm trying to use a pipeline build in Openshift 3.9 where I need to use the docker CLI. I can't figure out how to have the 'docker' command available in my pipeline.

I've tried the code below with declarative pipeline, but getting "docker: command not found"

```
pipeline {
            agent {
                docker { image 'node:7-alpine' }
            }
            stages {
                stage('Test') {
                    steps {
                        sh 'node --version'
                    }
                }
            }
          }
```

The code was copied from here:

https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/

I also tried the scripted version of it:

```
node {
    /* Requires the Docker Pipeline plugin to be installed */
    docker.image('node:7-alpine').inside {
        stage('Test') {
            sh 'node --version'
        }
    }
}
```

But getting the same error: "docker: command not found"

The docker pipeline plugin is installed (version: 1.17)
Openshift version: 3.9

Any suggestions? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be that you don't have `docker` installed on the node where you run your pipeline. You need to install it first. You cannot use `docker` command just after installing [Docker Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Docker+Plugin) without pre-configuration:

> By default, the Docker Pipeline plugin will communicate with a local Docker daemon, typically accessed through /var/run/docker.sock.

Comment: Thanks, you're right! It's more complicated that I thought! Redhat have a bunch of jenkins slaves available [here](https://github.com/redhat-cop/containers-quickstarts/tree/master/jenkins-slaves). There's none for docker but there's one slave for skopeo under 'jenkins-slave-image-mgmt'. Skopeo will do for what I need.

Answer (score 0):

Openshift provides Jenkins [slave images](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/using_images/other_images/jenkins_slaves.html) of three types,

1. Maven supported
2. Nodejs supported
3. Base image

Neither of them have docker installed and believe me, [that's not a good idea](https://jpetazzo.github.io/2015/09/03/do-not-use-docker-in-docker-for-ci/).

In Openshift, Jenkins runs as [Pod](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/)( running the docker container inside), and you want to get the docker within the container. So if you want to make docker available,

1. you have to create a jenkins slave image by extending the base image and add docker to it
2. Push it to the registry
3. Start using it!

But, do above if you really really want that, just a word of caution ;)

Comment: Interesting! Thanks! I think I skopeo will do. Otherwise the docker API as suggested in the article. I'm curious though about how does Openshift injects the docker socket into a custom builder (exposeDockerSocket field of customStrategy)